# bash su with parameters in init script

Tags: bash, init, su

In an init script I would like to call another script with a different user (in this case the catalina.sh from tomcat) and pass additional parameters.

I have tried something like this:

```
if [ $USER == "root" ]
then
  CMD="/bin/su ${TOMCAT_USER} -c"
fi

$CMD $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force
```

However, this fails as 'stop' and the other parameters are treated as a individual files and not as a parameter to the script and that files obviously don't exist. I have tried to work around that by using "$(printf())" to construct the necessary command, but haven't been able to find a working solution. Any ideas how I could pass additional parameters to that script?

**Edit:**

Providing more context in case the current user already is the required user. This is an ugly workaround which seems to solve the problem:

```
 if [ $USER == "root" ]
then
  CMD="/bin/su ${TOMCAT_USER} -c '"
  PST="'"
elif [ $USER == "${TOMCAT_USER}" ]
then
  CMD=''
  PST=''
else
  exit 1
fi

bash -c "$CMD$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force$PST"
```

Comment: we need to see catalina.sh

Comment: @suspectus [catalina.sh](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/bin/catalina.sh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any of these 2 ways to run a command line:

```
bash -c "$CMD '$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force'"
```

OR

```
eval "$CMD '$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force'"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work on SLES: `env: /bin/su tomcat /srv/tomcat7/latest/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force No such file or directory` for the second answer and the first answer leads to: `/bin/su: Invalid option -- o`

Comment: weird, does `eval "$CMD $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force"` work?

Comment: unfortunately that gives the same error: `/bin/su: Invalid option -- o`

Comment: This works when switching a user, however does not work in case switching the user is not necessary/possible. However, that's actually not what I was asking for, so marking this answer as accepted. I created some not-so-nice workaround by moving the single quotes to the cmd variable and adding a postfix, which contains the ending quote. Probably I'll still find a nicer solution to this.

Comment: Oh ok, but what is the scenario when switching the user is not necessary/possible?

Comment: I added more information to the question. Basically if you are the user, that is the user that runs tomcat, you may directly start tomcat by using the init script. If you are root, than the user is switched to the correct user. My workaround seems to work, but is kind of quite ugly.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid extra quoting problems you can simply wrap this in a function:

```
run_as_tomcat_user() {
    if [ "${USER-root}" = "root" ]
    then
        /bin/su ${TOMCAT_USER} -c "$@"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}
run_as_tomcat_user $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 20 -force
```

A couple notes:

- `"${USER-root}"` ensures that the code won't fail if for some reason `USER` is empty or even unset. Otherwise if by some coincidence the root user has run `unset USER`, it will still try to run with the correct user.
- `"$@"` expands to every argument, properly quoted, and as such is considered a safe way to reuse parameters.

Comment: that unfortunately results in an error on SLES `/bin/su: Invalid option -- o`

Comment: @codeySmurf Try `set -x` to see what it's actually executing.

Comment: I added `set -x` to the beginning of the run_as_tomcat_user() function. This is the output: http://pastebin.com/kGfyzsiV

Comment: "**Stoping** Tomcat"? Unicode quotes around help output? Looks like you're not using standard tools at all.

Comment: are you referring to that line `echo "Stoping Tomcat" `? What's wrong with it? Is it just the typo? I am not sure what you mean by 'standard tools'